Mono.Linker Error 'AndroidX.Collection.SparseArrayCompat Com.Airbnb.Lottie....' assembly: 'Lottie.Android.dll' AndroidX.Collection.SparseArrayCompat
In Xamarin project, lottie package throwing error while creating the release build in Android after update  library Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (123.3.1.2), Xamarin.Firebase.Iid (121.1.0.14), Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs (4.2.0), Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android (1.1.4.1)
Below is the complete error:
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'AndroidX.Collection.SparseArrayCompat Com.Airbnb.Lottie.LottieComposition::get_Characters()' in assembly: 'Lottie.Android.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve AndroidX.Collection.SparseArrayCompat
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()

I try this solution https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/821 but nothing.
Any idea?
thk

looking for a solution they told me to update the 'AndroidX.Collection' library, but I didn't have this library installed.
I installed the 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection' library (1.4.0.2) and the release build was successful
